# In Node.js, what are some ways to manage several memory/CPU intensive asynchronous operations?

Tags: node.js

In order to understand asynchronous programming, and specifically node.js, I created a small application that creates a web-based image gallery from a directory full of images.

When a browser is pointed at the directory (I'm using Express for the middleware/routing, and Jade and Bootstrap 3 for the views/presentation), the application loads up all the images in the directory, slices out 12 of them (there's a pager that allows the user to recede/advance 12 images at a time), and generates thumbnails using GraphicsMagick via the [gm module](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/).

If the original images are fairly small, the thumbnail generation is not particularly memory/CPU intensive, but if they're bigger, the app will sometimes run out of memory and die.

As I said, I'm a relative node.js beginner, and I don't have a solid Comp Sci background, but I'm familiar with concepts like garbage collection, etc. What are some methods of managing memory and processor usage that won't have a negative impact on the overall speed of the application from the user's perspective (i.e., won't make thumbnail pages load any slower).

The logic in question is [in this file](https://github.com/paulburton0/nodegallery/blob/master/list.js), which I've tried to comment to make it comprehensible. I'll reiterate once more that I'm not a professional programmer, nor am I a node.js expert, so I'm sure stylistic faux pas abound. Please feel free to critique anything, I'd be glad to have any feedback. (I'm just happy I've grasped it enough to get the thing to work.)

Comment: How are you calling `gm` on those 12 image, and what are you doing with the output that is created? Posting some code might be useful.

Comment: When you say "loads up all the images in the directory", do you mean, reads them into memory—and then makes thumbnails for 12 of them? How many images are there in the directory?

Comment: I've edited the question to include a link to the file on Github (I didn't want to paste 300+ lines of code into my question).

Comment: There are two steps: first, the entire contents of the directory are loaded into an array that just contains an object for each item in the directory, and each object contains things like the pathname, absolute path, etc. Second, a slice of that array is created that contains only 12 items. For each of those items, a thumbnail is generated. As far as I can tell, the first operation is not where the hang up is. There are thousands of files in some of the directories, and it's slurping them up without a problem. It seems to be the 12 async instances of gm that is causing issues.

Comment: @PaulBurton0 and it's not just that 12 instances of GM (AFAIK, the `gm` module spawns a new process for each instance) running that are causing memory to deplete? Without going over your code in details, I do notice that there may be various situations where you don't call the callback function.

Comment: @robertklep as far as I can tell, it _is_ the 12 concurrent instances of GM that are depleting the memory (it only happens when there are large-ish images being processed). I'm not sure what you mean by "don't call the callback function." Are you talking about the gm callback?

Comment: @PaulBurton0 if your hardware can't handle 12 instances of GM (the external program, not the Node module), you may have to look into something like [`async#eachLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachLimit) or [`async#queue`](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue). Regarding the callback: it seems to me that there may be situations where you're not calling the callback starting [here](https://github.com/paulburton0/nodegallery/blob/master/list.js#L31) (say if you're hitting dirs with just `.html` files in them). But again, I didn't go over the code in great detail.

Comment: @robertklep I see what you're saying about the callback. This may be one of those stylistic no-nos that I don't know about. The callback is passed through that `map` into the final call to `composeResults`,  where is is returned. As for the memory issue, you're completely correct that the root of the issue is that the server is pretty anemic in terms of hardware. I guess I could restate my original question as "if the process overcomes the physical capabilities of the hardware, what mechanisms/practices are there to mitigate that?"

Comment: @PaulBurton0 but _only_ if you call `composeResults` will the callback be called. There seem to be situations where `composeResults` could not be called.

Answer (score 0):

We've established that running 12 instances of GM is causing issues, especially when they have to process large images.

You could consider using [`async#queue`](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) (or the closely related [`async#eachLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachLimit) and [`async#mapLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#mapLimit)) to run the bulk of the code that you now have in `composeResults()`.

To give an example on how that would work, consider a queue with a concurrency of 2:

```
var async = require('async');

var someTaskThatTakesTime = function(item, taskDone) {
  // We'll fake a long-running task by using a timeout
  console.log('START', item);
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('DONE ', item);
    taskDone();
  }, 1000);
};

var queue = async.queue(someTaskThatTakesTime, 2);

for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  queue.push(i);
}
```

In your case, `someTaskThatTakesTime()` will run the thumbnail generation code. It would take a single file as "task", generate a thumbnail for it, and call `taskDone` when it's done.

Because of the concurrency limit, it will prevent more than two instances of GM running. You can easily see that happening in the example code above.

It would require some restructuring of your code. One possibility would be to first gather all the files that need to be processed into an array and process that array (in which case `async#eachLimit` makes a bit more sense than using a queue).